# Regex for URL matching that ignores query parameters

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a regular expression that matches the following URLs:

```
http://test.com/bobs/your/uncle/1
http://test.com/bobs/your/uncle/5
http://test.com/bobs/your/uncle/5?tab=1
```

But does not match the following URLs:

```
http://test.com/bobs/your/uncle/1/brah/5
http://test.com/bobs/your/uncle/1/brah/5?tab=2
```

I tried the following regex

```
/bobs/your/uncle/\d+\??
```

Which works for the first three URLs above, but not the last two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/bobs/your/uncle/\d+(?:\?|$)
```

`(?:\?|$)` will match `?` or end of input after your desired input URIs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use start and end anchors :

```
'bobs/your/uncle/\d+\??[^/]*$'
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/pP2fL1/1

you can use `[^/]*` to match some extra strings like `tab=1` which match any thing except `/`.

Comment: Should have been a bit clearer in my question, but I actually wanted to ignore the domain as well, since I'm working with localhost as well as the online staging environment. So match both `http://test.com/bobs/your/uncle/1` and `http://localhost:8080/bobs/your/uncle/1`. But I wasn't clear in my question, so I'm still giving you an upvote since it works if I remove the the start anchor and the domain.